# VCTargetsPath is wrong when building with MSBuild on build server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

In my C++ project, `Test.wcxproj`, I have the following configurations defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then I have the **problematic** import of the default C++ properties:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
```

When my build server builds my MSBuild project file (configuration is `Release` and platform is `Any CPU`), I get this error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

The relevant parts of my `MSBuild` project file look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.csproj" />
   <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.vcxproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
    <OutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildOutput\$(Configuration)</OutputFolder>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</SolutionDir>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<Target Name="Compile">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFiles)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(OutputFolder)\$(MSBuildProjectName);SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir)\" />
</Target>
```

### The problem

In my `MSBuild` project file, I am using `ToolsVersion="12.0"`. `Visual Studio 2013` is indeed installed, so I don't understand why it chooses to use `v4.0\v110`. Are my project configurations for some reason skipped by `MSBuild`? I guess I could somehow override this folder using the `/p` switch, but I want my `.proj` file to be self-contained.

Comment: Can you please provide us property PlatformToolset of that project?
It looks like you build vc2012 project on build machine where vc2012 wasn’t installed or you explicitly pass PlatformToolset property from command line.
v110 is vc2012 platform toolset.
v120 is vc2013 default platform toolset.

Comment: We upgraded a vc2010 project using VS2013. Now it says "v120" everywhere in the project file. We don't specify a PlatformToolset from command line. I'm starting to suspect that the build machine has some VC11 beta fragments left.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue. Ever solve it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, my build definition was configured to build my `.sln` file instead of my `.proj` file. I remember configuring it to build the MSBuild project, but somehow it seems to have reverted to the Solution.

Anyway, I found two solutions to the problem:

1. Make sure to build the `.proj` file (where the tools version is indeed set to `12.0`).
2. Explicitly set the [VCTargetsPath](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75c3e6c2-3c24-49b8-8cd4-e0de3d8c157c/why-does-msbuild-look-for-v110-directory-for-the-microsoftcppdefaultprops-file-with-vs2013?forum=msbuild).

Comment: i needed to update env and `Explicitly set the VCTargetsPath`

Answer (score 10):

Try to set up environment variable

```
VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

or pass it explicitly as property to msbuild on commandline

```
msbuild.exe <project or solution to build> /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

I think it is because Microsoft tries to keep compatibility with older Visual Studios.

see [Visual Studio project compatibility and VisualStudioVersion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was building an upgraded sln containing a vcxproj file via msbuild - this was constantly giving error below - now it works! 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and thenselect "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools. [D:\Projekt...