# error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props" was not found

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When I try to build one project with Visual Studio 2017, I got following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.14.props(47,3):
>   error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props" was not
>   found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk.

Why it imports the `V140\Microsoft.cpp.props`, I did not install Visual Studio 2015 on my PC.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to Clean the solution and build again.  By the way, what kind of project are you building?

Answer (score 2):

> error MSB4019: The imported project “C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props” was not found

If you build the project with MSBuild command line, you should specify the parameter `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0` in you command line, like:

```
msbuild.exe <project or solution to build> /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0
```

Check the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076303/vctargetspath-is-wrong-when-building-with-msbuild-on-build-server) for some more details.

If you build it with Visual Studio 2017, you can overwrite the value of `$(VCTargetsPath)`:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\

Also you can try to install the Visual Studio 2015 compiler tools:

[image]

Hope this helps.